# How to train a neural network where computing the loss requires multiple object values?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function

I want to train a function that given metadata about an image produces hyper-parameters for an algorithm which operates on the image.

My understanding is (please forgive me I'm a novice here) a neural network would suit this purpose.

I want to train a function:

```
def myHyperParameterFunction(a,b,c,...):
  return (one,two,three,...)
```

(This being a neural network starting with `keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(n,))` and ending with `keras.layers.Dense(m)`)

Which produces hyper-parameters for another algorithm:

```
def myAlgorithm(image, (one,two,three,...)):
  return newImage
```

By using `myAlgorithm` a cost function can be formed:

```
def lossFunction(true_image, image, (one,two,three,...)):
  return true_image-myAlgorithm(image, (one,two,three,...))
```

Looking at [the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) it seems I can only defined a loss function in terms of 2 variables `y_true` and `y_pred`, this seems to make this impossible. Possibly I could get around this by `y_true` being an index to arrays which contain `image`s and `true_image`s, but this feels a rather awkward solution (notably the object type of `y_true` cannot be `numpy.ndarray` so I cannot package both images in).

In summary, it seems the problem is that to compute the loss requires an additional external value (that being `image`, where `y_pred` is `(one,two,three,...)` and `y_true` is `true_image`). I am not bound to tensorflow, any tool or framework which helps with this I would be interested in.

How could I solve this?

Comment: I won't vote to close, but this seems to be the kind of question for which the Data Science Stack was created to address.

Comment: @Dave It's always tricky with these, both data science and cross validated mention `Machine Learning` and it is still programming so overflow still in mind. But I'll trust you know this best.

Comment: I didn't fully understand from where your external variables come. However you can use a wrapper for your loss function to pass external variable. Something like the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68121500/2423278) which passes the weights to a loss function.